# Point of no-electrocution

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, ideal

I have a brief question. Imagine a simple, ideal circuit. An extremely powerful battery, with each end connected to each end of a resistor via copper wire. With a resulting current enough to kill.

If I understand correctly, there is a voltage drop between both ends of the resistor, from highest voltage to lowest voltage. Thus, in the precise center of the resistor, the voltage vs. the ground is **exactly** zero. Thus, I, connected to the ground, could touch that (ideal) point with my (ideal) finger and not be electrocuted at all.

Is this reasoning correct? (I'm not going to do it, I'm just curious)

**Edit for clarity:**

An open circuit is grounded. Then it is made to float in mid-air. I have no reason to think the voltage vs the ground would change, even if it is no longer touching it. So zero voltage vs the ground.

Then floating circuit closes. Half of the circuit will have positive voltage vs the ground. Half of the circuit will have negative voltage vs the ground. There are two points in the circuit with zero voltage vs the ground. Is this incorrect?

Comment: If your circuit is floating (that is is not grounded anywhere) there is no way to know what would be the potential relative to the ground anywhere in it.

Comment: The voltage is zero relative to ground, at whatever point the circuit is referenced to ground by grounding it there. I could have a circuit with a 1 V battery and resistor, such that the two ends of the resistor are at 100000000 V and 100000001 V relative to ground. If there were enough capacitance between the circuit and ground, *that* could kill.

Comment: Birds put their feet of high voltage power lines carrying high currents and don’t get hurt.

Comment: @nanofarad, count your zeroes!

Comment: If you are standing on ground, and touch a connector with 0 voltage compared to ground, there is no reason why you should get a shock or be electrocuted. But the rest of your question does not make sense to me. I don't see why you picked the middle of the resistor to be at ground. Usually people ground one side or the other of the power supply.

Comment: Maybe if there were two batteries in series, and the common node was grounded.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Done, thank you for catching my silly typo.

Comment: @HandyHowie but do the birds touch the ground?

Comment: @mkeith No part is grounded. It was grounded when the circuit was built, but not anymore. While open, the circuit will remain at the same voltage as the ground, even when floating. Why would it change? When closed, half of the circuit gains high electric potential, and half gains low electric potential, vs the ground. The center of the resistor will remain equal to the ground. While floating.

Comment: @JuanPerez, in an ideal world, whichever part of the circuit was grounded would stay at ground potential after being disconnected. So if the center of the resistor was at ground potential, then disconnected from ground, it would, theoretically, remain at ground potential. However, it is also the case that if the battery is not connected to ground, then any one part of the circuit could be safely touched. In the real world, potentials drift with time, and isolated bodies may end up with large potential differences between them.

Comment: @JuanPerez  I think your problem may be a misunderstanding of the word "floating".   In electronics, it does NOT mean "something floating in the air", like a helium balloon.   It means floating ELECTRICALLY.   When something is ELECTRICALLY floating, that means it has NO DEFINED VOLTAGE relative to ground (or whatever else).   All voltages are RELATIVE.

Comment: @HandyHowie  Actually they DO get hurt (sometimes).  On REALLY high voltage lines, their sharp beaks create coronal discharges.   So they get zapped in the mouth.  I imagine that has to be quite uncomfortable!!    That's why you don't see 'em sitting on those kinds of lines almost ever.

Comment: @kyleB I thought any two points have a defined voltage between them, even if they are not electrically connected

Comment: @SolarMike There was no mention of either of the battery terminals being connected to ground, so your statement is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is, if you stand on GND and touch CENTER, theoretically, would you get shocked or electrocuted? The answer is, theoretically, no. You would not. CENTER should be at the same potential as GND, so no current would flow through your body. Of course, I would not suggest anyone actually try this! If any part of the circuit is not quite right, then injury could result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2IZlq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So what about with only one battery as the OP stated?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't understand that part of the question, so I modified it so it would make sense to me. As others have said, if the battery is in no way connected to ground, then the potential of any point to ground is kind of undefined, and in theory any one part of the circuit could be touched safely (in theory!).

Comment: I don’t fancy testing theory in this case either :)

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not reason correctly.

While you are grounded, touch any part of the resistor, or its ends, or the battery poles, and the point you touch will very quickly drop to 0 V with respect to ground.

There will be a very brief flow of current through you, discharging the capacitance between the battery+resistor circuit and ground. This capacitance could initially be charged up to any voltage. However the capacitance will typically be very small, so even with a stray charge of many kV on it, you would be unscathed, though possibly surprised. Have you ever touched a metal filing cabinet in a carpeted office in winter's low humidity conditions?

If one battery pole was connected to ground by a wire, and you touched the other one, then a nasty current could flow through you.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps what I should have asked is this: The circuit is un-grounded, and I connect a capacitor to a part of it. If I do it to the negative voltage part of the circuit, charge will briefly flow from the capacitor to the circuit. If I connected it to the positive voltage part, charge will briefly flow from the circuit to the capacitor. But, if I connected it to the very center, then no charge will flow at all in the capacitor. Is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: @JuanPerez in an ideal circuit you defined, there is no closed loop for the charges to build up or flow anywhere, so no matter what point of the battery or resistor you choose to connect to ground there will flow no charges.

Comment: @JuanPerez The capacitor is already there, a stray capacitance from all parts of the circuit to ground, with a value in the order of 10 pF to 100 pF for typical geometries. If that stray capacitance is on average zero-charged, then what you say is true. However, it only takes walking across a carpet, or pulling a jumper over your head, to create 10s of kV on that stray capacitance, rendering the voltage of the battery rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

No, not correct.

First of all, if the battery is not even connected to ground at any point, there is no point that is at ground voltage.

And at the center of the resistor the voltage would not be zero but half of the battery voltage.

And since it is an ideal circuit, it is isolated from ground like you and you can touch any one point in the circuit safely, in theory that is.

Comment: If I throw a piece of copper into the air, it is no longer grounded, but it would still have the same electric potential as the ground. Likewise, if I un-ground an open circuit, it would remain at zero voltage vs the ground, even floating. If I then have it close, part of the circuit will increase in voltage vs ground, and part of it will decrease in voltage vs the ground. And a point in the circuit will be at zero voltage vs the ground. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why it would do that? Why would connecting a resistor to battery to close a loop would in any way change the relative potential of battery terminals in respect to ground? If battery negative terminal has million volts compared to ground when current not flowing via resistor, it would have exactly same million volts compared to ground when current flowing via resistor.